# High i/o while running AQL in arangodb

Tags: arangodb

I am investigating the performance issues in arangodb I am having. I have noticed that it does a heavy i/o (read operation specifically) while performing certain AQL. I have following questions in my mind:

1. What's actually loaded into physical memory. Is it the write ahead log file, datafile or Journal
2. If I assume that all 3 are loaded, then why there should be an i/o while reading the data
3. AQL runs on Journal/datafile or it takes write-ahead log file data into account also.
4. If it runs only on Journal/datafile then it's possible that we have new data in write-ahead file but the aql won't return that

System is not using any swap at all. But still AQL run time is increasing. it's taking as high as 10 sec sometimes to run. I did a iotop on the arangodb and I see that this (see below) particular commands does a heavy read. It is as high as 15 mbps read.

" 2320 be/4 arangodb   10.69 M/s  149.39 K/s  0.00 % 22.48 % arangod -c /etc/arangodb/arangod.conf --uid arangodb --gid arang~emp-path /var/tmp/arangod --log.tty  --supervisor [[dispat_def]]"

Answer (score 2):

ArangoDB keeps all of the above in memory and AQL considers everything that has been written and committed to the database, regardless of whether it still resides in the write-ahead-log or not.

Is it possible that your system has run out of main memory to map all this data? That could explain the high i/o

Comment: Edited the question and put a bit more information at the bottom

Comment: Output of iotop -u arangodb: 

2320 be/4 arangodb   10.69 M/s  149.39 K/s  0.00 % 22.48 % arangod -c /etc/arangodb/arangod.conf --uid arangodb --gid arang~emp-path /var/tmp/arangod --log.tty  --supervisor [[dispat_def]]

Comment: First of all, are all the collections loaded that the AQL query accesses? After a server start or restart, the first query on a collection might load the collection fully. This might produce lots of I/O for the first time, but not when the query is repeated afterwards. Another potential issues is that the system runs short on RAM while the query is running. Then I/Os may also increase a lot. Can you watch top or other sources for the system's overall memory usage?

Comment: Yes, collection are preloaded before the queries access them. I am watching i/o, cpu and physical memory continously. Physical memory usages is definitely about 80% but swap usage is still 0. CPU usages max out to 75%. So, I am guessing I am still not running out of the RAM. The i/o in the begning is good and not much. This performance lag is not at the startup but on a more than 2 hours running arangodb.

Comment: AQL queries, even if read only, allocate memory for their intermediate results. It is possible that the OS satisfies these memory allocation requests by unloading pages from arangod's collection datafiles. That may cause a lot of follow-up I/O when these pages are accessed again, either by the AQL query itself or other operations on the data. Whether or not and when this happens at all depends a lot on OS and VM configuration so it's hard to tell from here.

Comment: Is there a specific query that causes the I/O peaks or is it happening seemingly randomly after some time the server is up? If the latter, how does physical memory usage change over time? Is the memory usage exceptionally high when the I/Os start, at least when comparing the memory usage to phases before when there are less I/Os?

Comment: 'unloading pages from arangodb collection datafiles' that makes much sense. I am debugging it more and post my results soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78350/discussion-between-deepak-agarwal-and-stj).

Answer (score 1):

As stj mentions

> AQL queries, even if read only, allocate memory for their intermediate results. It is possible that the OS satisfies these memory allocation requests by unloading pages from arangod's collection datafiles. That may cause a lot of follow-up I/O when these pages are accessed again, either by the AQL query itself or other operations on the data. Whether or not and when this happens at all depends a lot on OS and VM configuration so it's hard to tell from here

It was the issue of Main memory being exhausted due to intermediate results.